# Fatal error when using withMemoryRebound in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate

I have the following code to create a table for sampling an image in iOS using the Swift accelerate functions

When I rebound the memory to UInt16 which the table creation expects from Int which is the original type I get a fatal error.

```
var arr = Array<Float>(repeating: 0, count: 163840)

arr.withUnsafeBufferPointer{
    arr_pointer in do {
         arr_pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self){ // This causes a FATAL ERROR
             arr_r_pointer in do {
                 let table = vImageMultidimensionalTable_Create( arr_r_pointer.baseAddress!,
                            3, 3, dims_r_pointer.baseAddress!, kvImageMDTableHint_Float, 
                            vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags), nil )                          
                 vImageMultiDimensionalInterpolatedLookupTable_PlanarF( &srcBuffer,
                                       &destBuffer,nil,table!,
                                       kvImageFullInterpolation,
                                      vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone point out my mistake here?

Comment: What is `arr` ?

Comment: @OOPer  arr is an array containing values. I added code that is a placeholder. I fill the arr with values inside my code

Comment: Your `arr` is a nested `Array` and the outer `Array` (`arr`) has only 2 elements. So, your code access out of bounds and crash! Use a single dimension `Array` of `81920 * 2` elements.

Comment: I flattened the array and have 163840 elements now. it still gives me the same error unfortunately

Comment: I haven't checked the inner parts of your closure but you may have some inconsistency or misusage in your code. `dims_r_pointer`, `srcBuffer`, `destBuffer`... Please disclose all such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original array `arr` is an array of `Float`s

```
var arr = Array<Float>(repeating: 0, count: 163840)
```

but you're trying to bind the pointer to a `UInt16`

```
arr_pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self)
```

Comment: I need to rebound because vImageMultidimensionalTable_Create takes a UInt16

Comment: So initialise your array with `UInt16`?

Comment: array vals are in float

Comment: @PavanK, well that doesn't make `Float` and `UInt16` binary compatible, a `Float` is 2x bigger than `UInt16`. And you should check `Note` in `withMemoryRebound` function description.

Answer (score 1):

You should've read `Note` for `withMemoryRebound` function:

> **Note**
>
> Only use this method to rebind the buffer’s memory to a type with the same size and stride as the currently bound `Element` type. To
>   bind a region of memory to a type that is a different size, convert
>   the buffer to a raw buffer and use the `bindMemory(to:)` method.

Size of `Float` is **32** bits, size of `UInt16` is **16** bits, so they don't have same size and cannot be rebound.

So you should do something like this:

```
arr.withUnsafeBufferPointer { pointer in
    let raw = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(pointer)
    let uints = raw.bindMemory(to: UInt16.self)
    // use buffer pointer to `UInt16`s here
}
```

**But also note**, that each `Float` from initial array will be split in two `UInt16` that way. I don't know if that's what you need.